# Bootstrap - Two Nav bars not collapsing properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Hello Bootstrap Users**

I was wondering whether you could help me. Please look at screen-shot

[image]

of my two nav bars (**sample taken from Bootstrap website**) unfortunately when I I add some extra items to the menu the menu will not collapse as it should (See link above) This issue affects all devices / browsers.

Does anyone know what the problem might be ??

**See my code below** (sorry for the formatting)
    
  
    
      
        Toggle navigation
        
        
        
      
      FRIENDLY_NAME
    
    
      
         Home
        
           General 
          
            Group 2
             Link 1

Link2

Link3

Group 2

Link 4

Link 5

Link 6

Group 3

Link 7

Group 4

Link 8 42

Link 9 220

Link 10

```
  <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
  <li><a href='../navbar-fixed-top/'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> Help</a></li>
  <li class='dropdown'>
    <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench'></span> Settings <b class='caret'></b></a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span> Notification</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tower'></span> Members</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> New User</a></li>';
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='dropdown'>
    <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Administrator<b class='caret'></b></a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tower'></span> Profile</a></li>';
        <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-compressed'></span> Change Password</a></li>';
        <li class='divider'></li><li><a href='logout.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in'></span> Log Out</a></li>';
     </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Kind Regards;

pi4r0n

Comment: You've got few PHP echoes inside of HTML. Mind if you post entire code? (you could use Pastebin, or any similar service to do that).That might be causing the issues

Comment: @Nikola sorry I forgot to remove echos ;) but this isn't a problem. I have took this example from Bootstrap website and from what I can see this issue is there as well so it might be a framework issue which i can not solve :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">General <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Orders <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">Time Table</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Administrator <b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">link </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
         <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nobuts/s4MzB/1/)

Comment: unfortunately your example got same issue as my. Look at you demo and try to resize the width of the UI slowly. See  http://s14.postimg.org/b9n6f9clt/Still_The_Same.jpg@Wilf

Comment: Oh, I get the point now. Well, try to implement something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ajkochanowicz/wkqQU/

Comment: @Nokola the above solution isn't really mobile / tablet friendly :(

Answer (score 0):

We explicitly cover this in [the navbar docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)...

> ### Overflowing content
>
> Since Bootstrap doesn't know how much space the content in your navbar needs, you might run into issues with content wrapping into a second row. To resolve this, you can:
>
> - Reduce the amount or width of navbar items.
> - Hide certain navbar items at certain screen sizes using responsive utility classes.
> - Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable or add your own media query.